# $\lim_{z\to \infty} \frac{f(z)}{z}=0$ what can we conclude about $f$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a entire function such that $$\lim_{z\to \infty} \frac{f(z)}{z}=0$$

What can we conclude about $f$.

Using the change of variable $w=1/z$ we can conclude $\lim_{w\to 0} f(1/w)w=0$ so at $w=0$ we have removable singularity so we conclude that $f$ has removable singularity at $z=\infty$

Now what should be my next step?

Comment: Another one: [Find all entire function $f$ such that $\lim_{z\to \infty}\left|\frac{f(z)}{z}\right|=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1379823/42969).

Comment: @MartinR Thanks a lot. Did you search them using Approach.xyz? Somehow it did not show any results to me.

Comment: Yes: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bz%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Bf(z)%7D%7Bz%7D%3D0%24&p=1. – The second one is from the “Related” section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deduce from [Cauchy's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Consequences) that $f$ is constant. Indeed, if the Taylor series of $f$ centered at $0$ is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$, the$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N)(\forall r>0):\lvert a_n\rvert\leqslant\sup_{\lvert z\rvert=n}\frac{\bigl\lvert f(z)\bigr\rvert}{r^n}\to_{r\to\infty}0.$$

Comment: Obrigado  pela ajuda :)

Comment: $\ddot\smile{}$